# How to find OpenShift sandbox cluster admin password?

Tags: kubernetes, openshift, redhat, redhat-containers

I signed up for an OpenShift developer sandbox account. When I login to the UI with my email and password, I am logged into an account that is not admin(in my case, the account name is prava2597). If I go to the oc console from the UI, and if I try to list pods or basically do anything, I get this error:

```
Error from server (Forbidden): nodes is forbidden: User “prava2597" cannot list resource "nodes" in API group "" at the cluster scope
```

As I understand, the email of the account I used to create the OpenShift account should logically be the admin, but when I searched for this error, I see that there is a separate admin login and it can be done by executing command `oc login -u "system:admin"`, it fails with the error

```
error: username system:admin is invalid for basic auth
```

I am not sure where to find the certificate or token also to login using that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The OpenShift developer sandbox clusters are multi-tenant environments, and do not expose elevated permissions to any users.

There are several other environments, listed at https://www.redhat.com/en/technologies/cloud-computing/openshift/try-it, that provide other OpenShift experiences that wouldn't be multi-tenant.